# Angular 2 - passing DOM elements of two buttons to their respective functions

Tags: angular

I have two buttons in my Angular app that I created special stylings for.  The user can only highlight one button or the other, so I want to update both stylings of the two buttons in each function, which would look something like:

```
<button #allowButton class="btn btn-approve-unchecked" value="0" (click)="addToAllowList(allowButton, denyButton)">Allow</button>
<button #denyButton class="btn btn-deny-unchecked" value="0" (click)="addToDenyList(denyButton, allowButton)">Deny</button>
```

When I click these buttons and enter the function event, the code would look like:

```
addToAllowList(allowButton : any, denyButton : any) {
  allowButton.className = "btn btn-approve-checked";
  denyButton.className = "btn btn-deny-unchecked";
  ...more code here...
}
```

Same but opposite for the other function.  The first button is being passed and the styling is getting updated correctly, but the button not within the DOM scope is getting passed as null.  Is there a correct way to do this, or am I going at this wrong?

Comment: NOTE:  These buttons are dynamically allocated to the page, so I want to pass the actual DOM itself as a parameter so I don't update the whole column of buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it's cleaner to contol things like this with a state in your component:

```
isAllowHighlighted: boolean = true;

toggleAllow(allow) {
    this.isAllowHighlighted = allow;
}
```

In your template:

Allow
    
  
  
    Deny

**UPDATE**

I updated the answer for dynamically generated buttons and changed them to radio:

Component (that's one way to trigger change detection):

```
 log(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of [1,2,3]; let i = index">
  <div class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-approve-checked' : allow.checked, 'btn-approve-unchecked' : !allow.checked}" > 
    Allow
    <input #allow type="radio" name="someName{{i}}" value="allow" checked (change)="log('allow' + i)">
  </div>
  <div class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-approve-checked' : deny.checked, 'btn-approve-unchecked' : !deny.checked}" >
    Deny
    <input #deny type="radio" name="someName{{i}}" value="deny" (change)="log('deny' + i)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working code sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmfbrc

Comment: So, I remember why I coded it this way, and I should have made it clear in the question.  These buttons exist in a table, which has dynamically added rows in an *ngFor loop, so there could be one allow button, or several rows of buttons.  I wanted to pass the actual DOM element so I don't update all the rows.

Comment: It kinda looks like you might want a radio-button styled as a button rather than an actual button then. Would that be an option?

Comment: That could be an option!  I wanted buttons to style the page a little more, but I won't compromise functionality for style, lol

Answer (score 1):

Boris's solution is nice, but it can be made a little bit simpler. Considering a button can be 'on' or 'off'. One class binding is enough, which will allow us to ditch the ugly object binding.

So this

```
[ngClass]="{'btn-approve-checked' : isAllowHighlighted, 'btn-approve-unchecked' : !isAllowHighlighted}"
```

Becomes this `[class.checked]="allow"`

See my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9srtcx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

See the class binding section in the official documentation for more information [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding).